# How to get the index of a nested spinner in Adroid Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, indexing, nested, spinner

What I am trying to do is a kilometer calculator between one city and another.

I have already achieved that depending on the state selected in the first spinner the cities that correspond to that state are displayed. Now how can I get the positions of the selected cities so that depending on the city of origin and the city of destination I can calculate the distance.

```
package com.example.mainspinner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    TextView txtv1;
    TextView txtv2;
    Spinner combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4;
    ArrayAdapter<String> a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8;
    String Sp_Edo_Origen [] = {"Ohio",  "California", "Georgia"};
    String g1_cd_Origen [] = {"Columbus", "Dayton", "Cincinnati";
    String g2_cd_Origen [] = {"San Diego", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco"};
    String g3_cd_Origen [] = {"Atlanta", "Savannah"};
    String Sp_Edo_Dest [] = {"Puebla",  "Guanajuato", "Veracruz"};
    String g1_cd_Dest [] = {"Ohio",  "California", "Georgia"};
    String g2_cd_Dest [] = {"San Diego", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco"};
    String g3_cd_Dest [] = {"Atlanta", "Savannah"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        txtv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view2);
        combo1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Sp_Edo_Origen);
        combo2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Sp_Cd_Origen);
        combo3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Sp_Edo_Dest);
        combo4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Sp_Cd_Dest);
        combo1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        combo2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        combo3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        combo4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        a1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Sp_Edo_Origen);
        a2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, g1_cd_Origen);
        a3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, g2_cd_Origen);
        a4 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, g3_cd_Origen);
        a5 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Sp_Edo_Dest);
        a6 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, g1_cd_Dest);
        a7 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, g2_cd_Dest);
        a8 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, g3_cd_Dest);
        combo1.setAdapter(a1);
        //combo2.setAdapter(a2);
        combo3.setAdapter(a5);
        //combo4.setAdapter(a6);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int p, long id) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Pos: "+p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Valor: "+Sp_Edo_Origen[p], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Valor: "+a.getLastVisiblePosition();, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            if (a.getId() == R.id.Sp_Edo_Origen) {

                switch (p) {
                    case 0:
                        combo2.setAdapter(a2);
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "Valor: "+a.getLastVisiblePosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //caseta = 50 + 2;
                        //String resultado = String.valueOf(caseta);
                        // txtv1.setText(resultado);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        combo2.setAdapter(a3);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        combo2.setAdapter(a4);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (a.getId() == R.id.Sp_Edo_Dest){

                switch (p) {
                    case 0:
                        combo4.setAdapter(a2);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        combo4.setAdapter(a3);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        combo4.setAdapter(a4);
                        break;
                }

                if (a.getId() == R.id.Sp_Cd_Dest) {
                    }
                }
        }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside method `onItemSelected`, You can find the id of view that is the second parameter in this method. Compare this id to the id of city spinner and if it gets matched then find the position that gets selected(that is 3rd parameter int p) in the list of cities by which You filled the adapter of cities.

Comment: Mr thank you, could you show me a little piece of code of  how I can implement this? Please